# Does Android have a standard layout for Collapse or Accordion View?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, accordion

does Android offer a standard layout variant for displaying a collapse or accordion view in which, for example, 2 text views (1st title, 2nd body) can be integrated?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a framework layout.

I have used this lib https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView) from the Android SDK

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial)